# Javascript: Input validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a JS function to allow users to enter words in a input field with these req:

- max length of word 10 characters
- max length of string 30 characters

  ```
  onkeyup: return .split(' ').filter(
      function(what) {
          return /[\w\d]/.exec(what) != null && what.length <= 10 ? what : ''
      }
  ).join('').length > 0
  ```

Comment: Can you show us what have you achieved so far?

Comment: If you can show us what you've done so far we should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it necessary to use regex?

```
function isValid(str, maxlength, maxWordLength)
{

  if ( !str || str.length > maxlength ) //if the string is not null and length greater than max length
  {
    return false;
  }
  var strArr = str.split(/(\s+)/); //okay a bit of regex here :) to split by white space
  return strArr.some( function(value){ return value.length > maxWordLength } ); //if any value inside this array has value greater than maxWordLength
}

console.log( isValid( "asdas as", 30, 10 ) );
```

you can do it on keyup event of a textbox by doing

```
$( "#elementId" ).bind( "keyup", function(){ 

   isValid( $( this ).val(), 30, 10 );

} );
```

pure js

```
document.getElementById( "elementId" ).addEventListener ("keyup", function(){

   isValid( this.value, 30, 10 );

} );
```

Comment: @Markoo08 So call `isValid` in the `keyup` handler.

Comment: @Markoo08 if there are anymore issues, then create a fiddle and share the url